# Server response header Cache-Control immutable what format is correct for browsers to understand?

Tags: browser, http-headers, httpresponse

So with the Cache-Control response header i have seen a couple of different formats.

Like so
one website response (facebook)

```
cache-control: public,max-age=31536000,immutable
```

and another different website response

```
cache-control: max-age=31536000
cache-control: public,immutable
```

Does the header still work regardless of its formatting order or having multiple cache-control responses.

It is strange how websites set it differently and hard to know if it is working.